# How to use Active Directory user's account to login in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to add login page to my internal e-service, but this login must be read from Active Directory user's account:

What I did so far is:

`web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ADConnectionString" 
        connectionString="LDAP://dcsrv.****.gov.sa/CN=dcsrv,DC=****,DC=gov,DC=sa"/>
</connectionStrings>

<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".ASPNET" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>

<membership defaultProvider="MembershipADProvider">
   <providers>
      <add name="MembershipADProvider"  
           type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
           connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 
           connectionUsername="****.gov.sa\ADadministrator" 
           connectionPassword="ADPassword"/>
   </providers>
</membership>
```

`Login.Aspx`:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" onloginerror="Login1_LoginError">
      <LoginButtonStyle  />
          <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
          <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" />
       </asp:Login>
    </div>
</form>
```

`Login.Aspx.Cs`:
there is no important info, only login error message.

```
protected void Login1_LoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login1.FailureText = "Authentication failed!";
    }
```

But when I try it on my server I get an error which mentioned above

> *Authentication failed!*

So do I forget to add any information in `web.config` or import any library or any other info?

Comment: can you put a debug point into the Login1_LoginError method and investigate EventArgs e for the actual error message?

Comment: Daryal: the rror message which i recieve it now is:
The container specified in the connection string does not exist.
 in the line of <Provider> information.